# Where does Adobe Flash auto-updater store its run command?

Tags: boot, flash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Flash Player Automatic Updater on Windows Startup](https://superuser.com/questions/143553/flash-player-automatic-updater-on-windows-startup)

When I logged-in to my computer today I had the Flash auto-update window pop-up on me straight away. As much as I know the importance of regularly patching Flash, I'd like to know where and how the Flash updater is able to jump on me when I login.

I've looked in all the usual places:

Start Menu Startup folder: empty
HKLM\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run: nothing relevant found
HKCU\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run: nothing relevant found
Task Scheduler Library: nothing relevant found

I've also run Sysinternals Autoruns, and nothing is shown there either - it's not even a shell extension, Windows service, or anything else listed.

If Flash is able to get its auto-updater program to run on startup (and hide from me) then what's to stop malware from doing the same?

Comment: It uses RunOnce: [Flash Player Automatic Updater on Windows Startup](http://superuser.com/questions/143553/flash-player-automatic-updater-on-windows-startup)

Comment: you did not ask, but the via the latest versions of flash on a windows system, I go to the control panel, find the flash item (icon), and in the "advanced" tab, you can turn off updates permement (not monthly like some other stuff) . Flash is given more rights because 'it's trusted" there are certs involved, other things I do not understand that give certain programs more freedoms. it is not so much bypassing security, as it is "having security provided for it".